# Understanding how to Get Task feedback from XDocument.SaveAsync method

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF app, I use a button click to create an XML file. And get feedback from the async task if it is completed successfully and Display a message box.

#### Window.cs

```
 public partial class BindXml : Window
    {
        public BindXml()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Create_File_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            XmlCreator xmlCreator = new XmlCreator();
            Task task = xmlCreator.CreateXmlAysnc();
            MessageBox.Show(task.IsCompletedSuccessfully
                ? "XML Created Successfully."
                : "Wrong");

        }
```

#### XmlCreator.cs

```
        public async Task CreateXmlAysnc()
        {
            string filePath =
                "E:\\OneDrive\\Programming\\C#\\03_Csharp\\02_WPF\\06_DataBinding\\03_Binding\\09_BindXml\\data.xml";

            // Create a xml tree.
            XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(
                new XElement("StudentList",
                    new XElement("Student",
                        new XAttribute("Id", "1"),
                        new XElement("Name", "Tim")),
                    new XElement("Student",
                        new XAttribute("Id", "2"),
                        new XElement("Name", "Gary")),
                    new XElement("Student",
                        new XAttribute("Id", "3"),
                        new XElement("Name", "Tom")))
            );

            try
            {
                await using FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                await xmlDocument.SaveAsync(fileStream, SaveOptions.None, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

After I clicked the button and file created successfully. However, the message box shows that "Wrong". The task is not completed successfully.  Then I used the below code. The message box would show true.

```
Task task = xmlDocument.SaveAsync(fileStream, SaveOptions.None, CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.WhenAll(task);
                // Messagebox would show true
                MessageBox.Show(task.IsCompletedSuccessfully.ToString());
```

And if I add `Task.Wait()` into the Window.cs the application would block. Looks like the task is never completed but the file is already created.

What's the reason inside of it?

Answer (score 2):

With the *async and await pattern*, the idiomatic approach would be to `await` the *task*, and `catch` the *exception*.

Because you are coming from an *event handler* it's acceptable to use an `async void` to take advantage of the *async and await pattern*, and not worry about the raw *task*, or even worse trying to use `Wait` or any other blocking method.

Further more, when an *exception* is produced in an `async` method, it's placed on the *task* and will be thrown at the `await`, in turn enabling you to handle it fluently whilst also allowing the *continuation* to run on the original *context*.

**Example**

```
private async void Create_File_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
   try
   {
      XmlCreator xmlCreator = new XmlCreator();
      await xmlCreator.CreateXmlAysnc();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(e.Message); 
   }
}

public async Task CreateXmlAysnc()
{

   ...

   await using FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
   await xmlDocument.SaveAsync(fileStream, SaveOptions.None, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the using statement wrap the `SaveAsync` so that the `FileStream ` is closed and disposed after writing? If not, the file can not be accessed until garbage collection disposes the stream.

Comment: @clamchoda that is a Using declaration introduced in C# 8, which has the scope of the method, i.e. it encases the save async and everything in the method after it is declared